# How can I select an open window in GNOME Shell's Activities view using the keyboard?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

When I press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key in GNOME Shell (Ubuntu 11.10) I see all open windows. How can I select one of the open windows with the keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install the [Window Navigator Extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/10/).

If you press `ALT` you will see a number for each open window. Use the number to select the window you want.